# Gradle and latest version of libraries

Tags: android, gradle

Why does Gradle not show latest versions of used libraries? For example latest versions of ExoPlayer is 2.9.4, BlurView - 1.5, Android Billing Client - 1.2.1, but Gradle allows to add only 2.8.4, 1.2, 1.0 for these libraries.

Comment: Which version of AS you have used?

Comment: Please mention your gradle and Android Studio versions.

Comment: What happen if you set latest version manually?

Answer (score 0):

As per today's date the latest gradle version is:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
```

After updating gradle, Try following things to see updated versions with yellow marks in `build.gradle`.

> Invalidate Cache and Restart

or

> Close and open again `build.gradle`

Hope it will get refreshed and display latest versions.

Comment: You mean that you are not getting hints to update new versions of library. right?